# C program : why must in English input mode when outputing string to current active cursor?

Tags: android, c, windows

I am writing a C program to output a string to the current active cursor.

Here is my code:

```
void outputRawString(char* buf){

    INPUT input[2];
    int j = 0;
    wchar_t* output = c2w(buf);

    while(*(output + j)){

        input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input[0].ki.dwFlags = 0x0004;
        input[0].ki.wScan = (short)(*(output + j));
        //input[0].ki.wScan = (short)0x6211;
        input[0].ki.wVk = 0;
        SendInput(1, input, sizeof(INPUT));

        input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input[1].ki.wScan = (short)(*(output + j));
        //input[1].ki.wScan = (short)0x6211;
        input[1].ki.wVk = 0;
        input[1].ki.dwFlags = (KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | 0x0004);
        SendInput(1, input + 1, sizeof(INPUT));
        j++;
    }

}
```

The **c2w** is a function which is converting a **char*** to **wchar_t***.

```
wchar_t* c2w(const char *str)
{
    int length = strlen(str)+1;
    wchar_t *t = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*length);
    memset(t,0,length*sizeof(wchar_t));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,str,strlen(str),t,length);
    return t;
}
```

I need to output unicode string, both Chinese and English supported.

When I set my *input method* into **English** mode, the code above works well. However, When I set my *input method* into **Chinese** mode, nothing will be outputed.

By the way, the *input method* is developed by myself, I ouput the string through the **input method** program.

And the program working flow is:
The **input method** program uses **adb** to connect with an **Android** devices. I send data from **android** to my **input method** program (which run on Desktop Windows). When it recevies the data, I output the string to the current active cursor using **outputRawString**.

Comment: `wchar_t* output = c2w(buf);` looks suspicious. You take a `char *` and you get a `wchar_t *`. How is the conversion taking place? You create another buffer? If so when do you free it? You convert it in place? If so then you have to make sure buff is large enough to accommodate  the greater size of wchar_t

Comment: the **c2w()** now is in the edited question.

Comment: the question is : why this cannot work in English mode, while in Chinese input method mode can.

Comment: Does your output terminal support the unicode characters you want to output? For example, if the font used doesn't have glyphs for chinese characters, the output won't be visible.

Comment: you may misunderstood my question. When the input method mode is set to English, it can output unicode string(both English character and Chinese character). And when input method mode is set to Chinese, it outputs nothing. Because I don't input from my keyboard directly, I just send the unicode string from Android device to the **input method**.

Comment: How can `void outputRawString(char* buf)` and `wchar_t* c2w(const char *str)` accept Chinese characters as input?